# Texto importado de ficheiro de texto para textbox nao mostra os assentos correctamente

Tags: vb.net

Estou a desenvolver um notepad e estou com dificuldades a importar texto de um ficheiro de texto onde esse texto tem varios assentos, mas depois de importar para um textbox multiplo linhas , em vez dos assentos aparece um simbolo diferente.
Como na imagem abaixo
[image: Texto importado]

ja tentei algumas formas mas fica igual
este foi o ultimo codigo que tentei

```
OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Open Text File"
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Dim textFile As StreamReader

    textFile = File.OpenText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    TextBox1.Text = textFile.ReadToEnd()

    textFile.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

De facto depois de varias tentativas e de procurar encontrei 2 soluções no qual eu usei.
de facto a primeira situação foi de tornar a gravar o ficheiro de texto com utf-8 e a segunda apliquei em codigo que encontrei online
[Social msn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/65a00632-33d7-4652-9b5b-60a0679eb933/leitura-de-arquivo-txt-com-texto-acentuado?forum=vsvbasicpt)
Este e o meu codigo actual:

```
Public Function RemoveAcentos(ByVal texto As String) As String
    Dim charFrom As String = "ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ"
    Dim charTo As String = "SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy"
    For i As Integer = 0 To charFrom.Length - 1
        texto = Replace(texto, charFrom(i), charTo(i))
    Next
    Return texto
End Function

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    TextBox1.Text = RemoveAcentos(TextBox1.Text.ToString)
End Sub
```